# Automatically breaking down calendar events

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, calendar

I'm trying to create some sort of reservation system in SharePoint using a calendar list. It's been recommend to me to create events and add a column which allows a user to claim it. From there, claimed events would change color and only those who've claimed the event would have permission to unclaim the event.

This is what it would look like (see alternative option):
[image]

What I'd like to be able to do though, is instead of having to create three events like shown in the alternative option, creating 1 event (see original) and have that be broken down into 3 events or more, maybe using some form of drop down asking for intervals (ie. 15m, 30m, 1h). Based on the selected interval, it'd break the event accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at breaking this up into a few pieces.

Your Initial Event List, where events will be entered by event admins.  Create a column or columns that allow them to specify the available sessions/timeslots.  This could be simple or get complicated depending on how flexible you need it to be (i.e. multiple days, different intervals, etc).

Create a workflow that will then take those entries, and then create events in your calendar list as required.  You can create custom list views to display the events based on your selection criteria.

You will need an additional workflow that fires on the events if you want to change item level security as users claim the slots.  Once you change the permissions, if you do not include read permissions for all users, then the item will no longer be visible at all on your calendar except for the admins and the user that has rights to it.

A very rough workflow example would be (you would need more actions to manage all your inputs):
[image]

Comment: What I did was create a choice column called "Intervals" with choices: 15m, 30m, and 1hour. What would be ideal is if I created a 2 hour event from 12-2pm and selected 1hour interval, it would break this event into 2 events. If I said 30m, it would break it into 4, so on. Is that the same as what you mean?

Comment: The intervals you use doesn't matter that much, it will be the logic you use in the workflow to handle it.

Comment: But it's possible in foundation? Like I could create 1 event have it broken into multiple events using a workflow based on the selected interval? Because if it's not possible I don't want to waste my time looking into it

Comment: Nothing fancy here, you are using a custom list, calendar list, and out of the box workflows, all available on foundation.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. I'll try to follow what you've said and see if I can figure it out tomorrow or this week.

Comment: I've been looking around trying to figure out how I'd do this. To be honest I don't even know where to start. I'm using SharePoint Designer but I don't think I can actually set variables in there. I'm very new to this unfortunately.

Comment: here is a start:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-l40RQ3kd8  Also search on office.com for instance this is alist of workflow actions available out of the box http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx  One last note a good short read is here:  http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2010-workflows  - And last you may want to look at 3rd party options as alternatives (nintex and K2 are the leaders here , but there are dozens more)

Comment: Thank you, ill look into these and see if I can make some progress